# There are two errors, I can not solve it（ListView）

Tags: java, android, listview, gradle

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text, in the question itself, and provide a detailed explanation of the problems you're having.

Comment: `getText(a.context)` for the first issue

Comment: @dowswin Code is not at all readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your adapter initialization inside `onCreate`. You need to set the adapter to the `ListView` using `setAdapter`. Call `noftifyDataSetChanged` after populating the dataset `arr`.

Try this code,

```
private MyAdapter ma;

onCreate(){
    ...
    setContentView(R.layout.activty_main2);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_1);
    ma = new MyAdapter(this, arr);
    lv.setAdapter(ma);
    initData();
}

initData(){
    for(;;){
        ...
        arr.add(n);     
    }
    ma.noftifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You not having any blank constructor in MyAdapter,
you have to pass context and ArrayList to the adapter like,

```
MyAdapter ma = new MyAdapter(Main2Activity.this,arr);
```

[image]